# Lightning component issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Lightning SPA built with a couple of components embedded in it. When I use lightning out technology to display it on the VF page and it works fine. However, when I use LightningAppBuilder to load the component on the Home page, I'm getting the error where APStage2 is the name of a component within SPA. I don't know what's causing this issue. Anyone run into this same issue?

COMPONENT markup://c:APStage2 is missing required attribute 'name'

Wrapper Component snippet which embeds APStage2 Component

```
<div aura:id="stage1Div">
    <c:APBasicInfo partnerRecord="{!v.partnerRecord}" />

</div>

<div aura:id="stage2Div">
    <c:APStage2 partnerRecord="{!v.partnerRecord}" />
</div>
```

Component:

```
<aura:component 
  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
  forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" 
    controller="AffiliatePartnerApexController">
  <aura:attribute name="partnerRecord" 
  type="Affiliate_Partner_Onboarding__c" access="global" />
<aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:AffiliatePartnerDetailEvent"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="bubblingEvent" 
 type="c:AffiliatePartnerSPANotifierEvent" />
```

Comment: it is missing a required attribute 'name' -->  name="something"  =P

Comment: If so, how it would work on the VF page?

Comment: are you assigning name attribute from the wrapper in the  contorller? have you marked it @aura enabled? Instead of us speculating can you post your component and controller?

Comment: @JJSHHS you will need to share some code (a minimal reproduceable example preferably)

Comment: Try making a default value on your name attribute. Then use a design file to allow users to set the value from the app builder.

Comment: I'm guessing partnerRecord is null. I can't really tell as you probably need a bit more code up there.

Comment: I've added code snippets above. Pls take a look. If the partner record is NULL or for whatever reason, then the VF page also which exposes this should also not work. That's what really confuses me!

Comment: @Rao - yes, the controllers are auraenabled and there is no "name" attribute as such. Just one attribute called partner record

Comment: Can you try removing the flexipage + forcecommunity interfaces? I suspect it might be linked to those.

Comment: Also have you tried adding this to your component: `<c:APStage2 partnerRecord="{!v.partnerRecord}" name="test"/>` - again, I believe this is interface linked. Interfaces can define attributes that are automatically added to your code. If there was a name attribute and someone made it required, then this could occur.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I tried removing the flexipage + community interfaces, also added a new "name" attribute in the APstage2 component and passed in from the wrapper component. Yet, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63968/discussion-between-jjshhs-and-caspar-harmer).